# Android service + countdown = not working

Tags: android, service

Ok this got me really mad. Is there a restriction for services with countdowns?

I tried so many methods to make a countdown timer work in a service,but it always fails. It just never gets to the finish() part!

So is there a restriction with services and countdowns or what? Please help me...

Here is the service:

```
public class ss extends IntentService {

      public ss() {
          super("ss");
      }

      @Override
      protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        new CountdownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

     }

     public void onFinish() {
         executemymethod(); //it never gets here!
     }
  }.start();

      }



}
```

As you can see the code is simple and correct,but still the executemymethod(); never really executes! There are no errors... Please give me a solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this kind of thing you should be using a regular Service and not an IntentService. Here's what the docs say about [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

> Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

Since the countdown is asynchronous, the work is complete after you start the countdown timer. The IntentService then finishes immediately, and probably shuts down the thread.

Comment: yep,already using a normal service and it works like a charm...god...so lucky to have that android dev website...